# Unable to encode chinese characters on Tomcat

Tags: java

I am trying to encode Chinese character using the `HexToString()` function, but getting the correct Hex value, and when I am decoding the same values is getting changed every time.
Below is my String which I am trying to encode to Hex

```
String strChinese = "TEST NC 兌美元匯率新台幣，今(31)日午盤 ";    

replyMessage.setCaTitle(TextFormatHelper.GetHexString(strChinese)); 


public static String GetHexString(String stringToConvert){
        byte[] b = stringToConvert.getBytes();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(b.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            int v = b[i] & 0xff;
             if (v < 16) {
               sb.append('0');
             }
             sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
```

Not getting the correct Hex value, can someone please help here?

Comment: Do you mean `Hax` or `Hex`? And from what library is the class `TextFormatHelper` from? What is the result you get currently?

Comment: Below is the GetHexString called:

public static String GetHexString(String stringToConvert){
        byte[] b = stringToConvert.getBytes();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(b.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
         int v = b[i] & 0xff;
          if (v < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
          }
          sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @DivjotSinghBhatia Can you please add your code from comment to the question

Comment: Hi..TextFormatHelper is the utility class, sorry, its Hex, typing mistake.

Comment: Your conversion code is correct. What's the problem??

Comment: @DivjotSinghBhatia Please follow the Java Naming Convention and change `GetHexString` to getHexString`. Method names always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @DivjotSinghBhatia Regarding your problem: what makes you think that your code *does not* print the correct hex string?

Comment: @MCEmperor : When I am trying to decode the Hex code, I am not getting the correct chiness characters, instead I am getting question marks(?) at the place of chinese characters.
Even when I tried to use the online converter to convert it, then also I didn't got the correct data. I believe there is something wrong in String convertion to Hex.

Comment: @DivjotSinghBhatia I believe there is nothing wrong with the conversion itself. I tested it myself It is because of your encoding settings of either your OS or your browser or the website you're browsing to or your IDE. In which encoding is your file encoded? Those question marks are replacement characters. They are shown when the character's value is unknown or unrepresentable

Comment: Therefore: what *hex string* do you expect?